# How do I add a background image to an empty anchor tag without my text being displayed over the image?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, background-image, anchor

I am trying to put a background image on an empty anchor tag and display text 20px below that image. This is within a flexbox so that it is responsive as I resize my screen. Both the images and the text appear, but the text is displaying on top of the image when I want it 20px below the image. Does anyone have any suggestions?

My current HTML:

```css
#store {
  overflow: auto; 
  padding: 40px 0;
}
.splitpage {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0; 
  text-align: center;
}
#store p {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
#pants {
  background: url(layout1-assets/pants.webp);
  background-size: cover;
}
#shirts {
  background: url(layout1-assets/shirts.webp);
  background-size: cover; 
  text-align: center;
}
.container {
  width: 1040px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<section id="store">
  <div class="container flex wrap">
    <div class="splitpage" id="pants">
      <a href="#" aria-label="photo of our various types of pants"></a>
      <h2>Our pants</h2>
      <p>Description of pants here</p>
    </div>

    <div class="splitpage" id="shirts">
      <a href="#" aria-label="photo of our various shirts"></a>
      <h2>Our shirts</h2>
      <p>Description pf shirts here</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I completely misread your question at first because you set the image on the container, not the link and thought it was basically a depth problem. All you need to do is to set the link box model to block and give it the image background. Read my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you put the image on the container, not the link.

Since the div containing the background image is the container of your text, it naturally covers the whole area and your text appears on top of it.

You can move your image as the background of the link and set the link display model to block so that you can set its dimensions, making it an "image link". [Look into MDN for display model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

Here I have replaced your images with a red and blue background.

Just put back your images backgrounds and you're done.

```css
#store {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.splitpage {
  width: 50%; margin: 0; text-align: center;
}

#store p {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.imagelink {
   display: block;
   width: 100%; height: 200px;
}

#pants {
  background: red; background-size: cover;
}
#shirts {
  background: blue; background-size: cover; text-align: center;
}
.container {width: 1040px; margin: 0 auto;}

.flex {display: flex; justify-content: space-between;}

.wrap {flex-wrap: wrap;}
```

```html
<section id="store">
  <div class="container flex wrap">
    <div class="splitpage">
      <a href="#" aria-label="photo of our various types of pants" id="pants" class="imagelink"></a>
      <h2>Our pants</h2>
      <p>Description of pants here</p>
      
    </div>

    <div class="splitpage">
      <a href="#" aria-label="photo of our various shirts" id="shirts" class="imagelink"></a>
      <h2>Our shirts</h2>
      <p>Description pf shirts here</p>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: That worked to move the text! Thank you so much! However, there's now a scroll bar within just that section of my site. I tried moving the padding and margins around, but that didn't help. Any more suggestions?

Comment: look into height values. for Instance imagelink.height. Also the store.overflow: auto basically says to add a scrollbar when something overflows. compare with the height available for this section. if the content of an overflowing container is bigger that its fixed size then scrollbar will appear